# AngularJS flex box height in ng-repeat

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am making a complex table using ng-repeat combined with angular material's layout container directives. Each cell of the table then has it's own custom directive based on the index (even index is an input container, odd index is a score table). The issue I have is these custom directives are not filling the entire cell in height.

Here is the js fiddle:  [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkarv/8cyjcawr)

For example in the 2nd column, 1st row cell if I input multiple lines the 3rd cell table and 4th cell background colour (yellow) do not expand with the row height change. Also I need the 3rd col table to fill the entire the cell currently it height is less than 50% of the cell or parent div.

I've played around with display:flex with little luck, but I'm pretty sure I am doing it wrong. I really appreciate if someone can help with fixing my height issue. Thanks in advance!

Finally my html code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <style type="text/css">
    .table-row{
        border-left: 2px solid black;
        border-bottom: 2px solid black;
        }
    .table-cell{
      border-right: 2px solid black;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/template">
    <!--form-cell-input template-->
    <div style="background-color:blue">
      <md-input-container>
        <label>Title</label>
        <textarea ng-model="user.title" columns="1"></textarea>
      </md-input-container>
    </div>
  </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/template2">
    <!--form-cell-table template-->
    <div style='100%'>
      <style type="text/css">

        .table{
          table-layout:fixed;
          border-collapse: collapse;
          text-align: center;
          width:100%;
          height:100%
        }
         .cell{
          border-collapse:collapse;
          padding:0px;
          align:center;
         }
         .cell-risk{
          border-left: 1px solid black;
         }
         .cell-empty{
          border-bottom: 1px solid black;
         }
      </style>
      <table class="table" ng-class="{'cell-empty':riskLabel.z.rating==NULL}">
        <tr >
          <td class="cell"  style="background-color:black">
            <label class="md-caption" style="color:#757575">Score 1</label></br>                
          </td>
          <td class="cell cell-risk" style="min-height:60px;" rowspan="2">
            <label class="md-caption" style="color:#757575">Overall Score</label></br>             
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="cell" style="background-color:white" >
          <td>              
              <label class="md-caption" style="color:#757575">Score 2
          </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
  </script>


  <div  layout="column" ng-repeat="row in [0,1,2]" class="table-row" >
    <div  layout="row" >
      <div flex='10'><!--first index col-->
        #{{$index}}
      </div><!--end first index col-->
      <div flex><!--second col w/ repeat form-cell-->
        <div layout="column">
        <div flex>
          <div layout="row"><!--second col-->
            <div ng-repeat="col in [0,1,2]" class="table-cell" flex>
              <form-cell-input table-layout='tableLayout' ng-if="$even"></form-cell-input>
              <form-cell-table ng-if="$odd"></form-cell-table>
            </div>          
          </div><!--end second col-->        
        </div>
        <div flex style="border-top:1px solid black;border-left:1px solid black">
           Notes
        </div>
       <div><!--end subrow-->
      </div><!--end second col w/ repeat form-cell-->
    </div> <!--end layout row--> 
  </div><!--end layout column ng-repeat row-->
```

Comment: Wasn't able to solve it in the fiddle, but you are using an old version of angualr material. v1.0 has a layout align stretch property that looks like it does what you need: https://material.angularjs.org/1.0.0/layout/alignment

Comment: Thanks I've set-up another jsfiddle with angular material v1.0.0. I've tried the layout-align stretch but still no luck. http://jsfiddle.net/bkarv/8cyjcawr/

Comment: Updating the angular material 1.0.0 I managed to implement the stretch for the yellow cells. Having trouble with the cell table but I think I got the gist of it and will figure it out. Thanks for the tips. My updated js  http://jsfiddle.net/bkarv/aLexqqq9/